# Google Chrome is not showing all paper sizes in the "Print" dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

We have some custom paper size defined for our printing needs. When we are printing using Google Chrome it is always showing **Letter** as the default paper size, it is not showing our custom paper size in drop down list. This issue is machine specific i.e. we are getting this issue on Windows XP.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

i was able to solve my issue, i was defining paper size format in wrong manner and i also re-installed printers drivers than it worked perfectly.

Comment: It would be nice if you shared what you did to solve the problem so others might benefit...

Comment: This does not answer the question, if anything this should just be a comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is possible to change this. Others on various other sites like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/376618/how-to-change-default-page-print-size-in-chrome) and [Google Groups](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/wEQDDKKItY8) have indicated that it may be down to the individual printer.

As far as I can tell it selects "Letter", as it is the first/default option in the list as shown in the image below:

[image: Chrome Print dialog]

This would be a handy feature to have in Chrome, so it is worth posting a feature request on the Google Chrome help forum: https://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome

Until then, alas it seems like we don't have much hope :(

Comment: Sam i  have defined a custom paper size "GD"  for printers this paper size is not showing in that drop down..can you please suggest how to add paper size to chrome drop down

Comment: @singhm0077 just to clarify- the custom GD size you have defined, did you define it in the System printing dialog or in Chrome itself somewhere?

Comment: yes i have defined GD size using System Printing dialog

Comment: I believe the System Print dialog and the Chrome print dialog are separate, including any pre-defined page sizes (unless someone can show that I'm wrong and they're supposed to be linked). So based on this, I wouldn't expect any settings made in System Print to show or be accessible to Chrome print.

Comment: In addition, I did not find anywhere to make custom page sizes in the Chrome Print Paper Size option drop down. Looks like you're out of luck. :(